# Remote connect to SQL Server Standard Edition from PHP/FreeBSD

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2003, freebsd, freetds

Unable to connect to our company MSSQL server from one of our FreeBSD servers.

```
# telnet 192.168.1.51 1433
Trying 192.168.1.51...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.51: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

No firewall running on the MSSQL server, and i have opened the default port on the BSD-FW

```
00210 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 1433 in
00215 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 1433 out
```

Any ideas on this?

The specifics of the MSSQL server running on a Windows Server 2003

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about security tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated it MSSQL to Service Pack 4, and i'm now able to telnet to the server on the specified port. And also connect to the server from PHP with pdo_dblib

Answer (score 0):

Test whether you can connect from another non-local machine. If not TCP connections may not be enabled for SQL Server. Here are [instructions for enabling TCP/IP Connections with SQL Server 2000](http://ww2.recruitmentsystems.com.au/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=32)

Comment: I have tested, with telnet as you can see in the question. I don't need connection from non-local machines. What i have found out, is that the SQL server maybe needs to be updated to Service Pack 4...

Comment: By non local I mean "not the same machine that SQL Server is installed on" - I assume you don't have SQL Server installed on the FreeBSD box :-)

Comment: Ahh.. non-localhost ;) I updated it MSSQL to Service Pack 4, and i'm now able to telnet to the server on the specified port. And also connect to the server through PHP, but with limited success.