# MSSQL connection from PHP on FreeBSD

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, windows-server-2003, freebsd

As an extension of my question: [Remote connect to SQL Server Standard Edition from PHP/FreeBSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381787/remote-connect-to-sql-server-standard-edition-from-php-freebsd)

I'm trying to get our FreeBSD/Apache/PHP server to be able to query our WinServer2003/SQL-Server-2000 box. Please note that this is not for a public system, only for a internal reporting function - so performance is not the key at this point.
The initial question helped me prepare the MSSQL server for connection, and is now getting some kind of response from it. However I haven't got a successful connection to it.

I have tried PDO_dblib, mssql (FreeTDS) - haven't tried ODBC. I would prefer if I could get PDO to work, so that's what I'm aiming at here - and it's also the most succesfull of the two I tried.

**My PHP script that utilizes PDO:dblib**

```
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$servername = '192.168.1.51';
$port = '1433';
$serverdsn = $servername.':'.$port;
$username = 'webserver';
$password = '123456';
$dbname = 'oneServer_staging';

$sqlstatement = 'SELECT * FROM ordersp';

try 
        {
            $pdo = new PDO ("dblib:host=".$serverdsn.";dbname=".$dbname,$username,$password);
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            exit;
        }
exit;
```

***The result of this PDO:dblib script when running it in browser:***

```
Failed to get DB handle: SQLSTATE[28000] Login incorrect. (severity 9)
```

***And ind the MSSQL server's application log I find this:***

[image]

**EDIT after comment about FreeTDS**

**My PHP script that utilizes mssql_connect() / FreeTDS**

```
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$username = 'webserver';
$password = '123456';
$dbname = 'oneServer_staging';

$sqlstatement = 'SELECT * FROM ordersp';

$link = mssql_connect('MYMSDN', $username, $password);

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
```

***The result of this mssql/FreeTDS script when running it in browser:***

```
Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: MYMSDN in
/home/www/[..]/httpdocs/public/default/philip/oneserver-db-test.php
on line 17 Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL
```

***/usr/local/etc/freetds.conf***

```
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
        tds version = 4.2

        initial block size = 512

        # uses some fixes required for some bugged MSSQL 7.0 server tha
        # return invalid data to big endian clients
        # NOTE TDS version 7.0 or 8.0 should be used instead
;       swap broken dates = no
;       swap broken money = no

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
        dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
;       timeout = 10
;       connect timeout = 10

        # If you get out of memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.
        # (Microsoft servers sometimes pretend TEXT columns are
        # 4 GB wide!)   If you have this problem, try setting
        # 'text size' to a more reasonable limit
        text size = 64512

# A typical Microsoft SQL Server 2000 configuration
[MYMSDN]
        host = 192.168.1.51
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
        client charset = UTF-8
```

The file `/tmp/freetds.log` shows nothing when executing the script, however if i use `# tsql -C` command, it's updated.

Comment: Using FreeTDS, it should create successful connection. Are you trying to connect with default instance? If you use default instance, you don't need to add PORT parameter here.

Comment: @Wasim: I have added the FreeTDS stuff in the question. Do I need to configure `/usr/local/etc/freetds/interfaces.dist` for FreeTDS?

Comment: What is 'MYMSDN' on line: $link = mssql_connect('MYMSDN', $username, $password);?

Comment: @Wasim : I saw this in some other examples i found on the web. It refers to MYMSDN in the freetds.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following lines of code work?

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$username = 'webserver';
$password = '123456';
$dbname = 'oneServer_staging';
$servername = '192.168.1.51';

if (!$link = mssql_connect($servername, $username, $password)) {
   exit('Error: Could not make a database connection using ' . $username . '@' . $servername);
}

if (!mssql_select_db($dbname, $link)) {
   exit('Error: Could not connect to database ' . $dbname);
}
?>
```

Comment: No luck with your script, still receiving message that can't connect.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this line in your freetds.conf file?  Are you sure both sides are using UTF-8?

```
client charset = UTF-8
```

Here's the code I use to connect PHP to MSSQL from Ubuntu machines to Windows SQL Server, I don't know if it will help you or not but this code is up and running successfully right now so I know it works in our environment...

PHP:

```
<?php
try{
   $con = new PDO("dblib:dbname=$dbname;host=$servername", $username, $password);
}catch(PDOException $e){
   echo 'Failed to connect to database: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
   exit;
}
?>
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
# Define a connection to the MSSQL server.
# The Description can be whatever we want it to be.
# The Driver value must match what we have defined in /etc/odbcinst.ini
# The Database name must be the name of the database this connection will connect to.
# The ServerName is the name we defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
# The TDS_Version should match what we defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
[mssqldb]
Description             = MSSQL Server
Driver                  = freetds
Database                = MyDB
ServerName              = mssqldb
TDS_Version             = 8.0
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
# Define where to find the driver for the Free TDS connections.
[freetds]
Description     = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver          = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount      = 1
```

/etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
[global]
        # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  
        # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit 
        text size = 64512

# Define a connection to the MSSQL server.
[mssqldb]
        host = mssqldb
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
```

Comment: I have tried putting in what you have in your configs, unfortunately it don't work. I'm getting ´Failed to connect to database: SQLSTATE[HY000] Server is unavailable or does not exist. (severity 9)´
Guess the SQL server needs to be setup with ODBC too?